# control which icon will be the clickable icon over Google map in a situation of overlapping?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlap

I'm building an Android app that uses Google's map and on it icons of users. Due to the big number of icons in certain areas on the map (even in the maximum zoom-in) i experience an overlap of icons.
In this mode of overlap when you click on an icon for more information you get the info regarding the lower icon (in the group of icons that overlaps). I would like to get the info regarding the upper icon (in the group of icons that overlaps). 
How can I control which icon will be the clickable icon over Google map in a situation of overlapping?